# Why is there a +2 reputation for a post?

Tags: discussion

In the reputation page, it shows this:

```
+2  14 secs ago  upvote In C, should I define a function that takes no arguments with void or with an empty list?
```

While other upvotes are +10 which is correct. Why is it 2 for this particular post?

Comment: I guess because you reached max reputation.